# How to access a text file in server from another device

Tags: java, php

I have a txt file in my server.

I want to access the make changes to the text file from another device like a mobile browser by running a java program.

Code what I am trying is :

```
public static void writeToFile(String content) {
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("10.192.12.163//NETS//Mail//filename.txt"))) {

        bw.write(content);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Error:

```
 System cannot find the file
```

I am using XAMP server and my code is in location:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\NETS\Mail\filename.txt
```

How can I access this file from other devices using the ip address which is 10.192.12.163.

Comment: in which code you wanna do a change JAVA or PHP ?

Comment: I think changes needs to be done in the both the codes. But I am unable to figure out how should I proceed. ANy hints please

Comment: please be more clear. what are the changes? you want to pass values or change the code itself ?

Comment: I am accessing the server file so that when I run the php file, it uses the commandlines to run my java file and then create a txt file and write my data to it. But I am not sure how can this be achieved. If passing value helps then how should we proceed ?

Comment: you dont know how to execute java code in php ? you dont need echo if you want to execute code only

Comment: I know how to do that.
I have a computer that is my server. I have created php files on it.
using the ip address of the computer and connecting to the same accesspoint, I use my mobile browser to access the website which does is that runs the java code on my computer that is my server and that java code creates a file and writes to it on my server.
How can I manage the addresses using the mobile browser as when using same pc everything works fine but when mobile browser, file is not creted because of address issues. 
Hope my problem statement is clear now.

Comment: well if your code works on your computer but doesnt work on mobile it might be a network issue ? are you on NAT or Bridget Network ? also you can try to do same request by using API call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141850/discussion-between-learner-and-rodrane).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141854/discussion-between-learner-and-rodrane).